# AES-GCM cipher - Nonce vs IV

Tags: encryption, aes, initialization-vector, gcm, nonce

I am using a Python library called PyCryptodome, which offers the following API for AES-GCM ciphers:

https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/aes.html

As you see, IV is not applicable for GCM ciphers.

There are some C++ libraries that expect the user to specify the IV rather than the nonce.

Let's say that I get a message encrypted with a C++ library that uses a 16 bit IV. Later on, I want to decode this message using a Python library. Given that I know the key and the IV that was used, will I be able to properly decipher the message when I specify the nonce to be the IV?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The term for the parameter to AES-GCM that must be unique from message to message for any single key is sometimes called ‘nonce’ and sometimes called ‘IV’.

- The [security contract for AES-GCM](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/57648) requires that only that this never be repeated, and so it is appropriate to call it a *nonce*, meaning *number used once*.
- In contrast, for, *e.g.*, AES-CBC, there is a parameter for a 128-bit string that must be *unpredictable in advance* to an adversary, and which is usually called an *initialization vector*.

That's the distinction that PyCryptodome is getting at when it distinguishes the ‘nonce’ and the ‘IV’—although it says ‘IV’ for AES-CFB and AES-OFB too when really they just take a nonce.  However, in some *other* APIs, the corresponding parameter is always just called IV.  To be confident, you should draft some code using two different libraries—like one of the C++ libraries you have in mind—and make sure they can interoperate, and include known-answer tests with fixed keys, nonces, and messages, as test cases in your code.

**Caveat:** AES-GCM is *best* with a 96-bit (12-byte) nonce chosen sequentially as a message sequence number.  If you use a 128-bit (16-byte) nonce—as the PyCryptodome documentation *wrongly* recommends—it is *as if* you had chosen a 96-bit nonce *at random*, which means, because of the danger of a nonce collision, that there is a much smaller limit on the number of messages than if you had chosen a 96-bit nonce sequentially.

Comment: Why, exactly, is a 128 bit nonce the same as a 96-bit random nonce?   Looking at the AES-GCM implementation in OpenSSL, it's possible to use EVP_CTRL_AEAD_SET_IVLEN and set it to 16 bytes or 32 bytes or whatever you please.   And at that point a random number is probably better than a "possible to mess up" increment.

Comment: @ErikAronesty If you use a nonce other than 96 bits, GCM derives an initial block pseudorandomly from the nonce—so even if you choose a (say) 64-bit nonce _sequentially_ you can get a nonce collision long before $2^{64}$ messages.  The story is actually a little more complicated, and the originally claimed security reduction was wrong because the designers of GCM made a mistake in studying how non-96-bit nonces work.  See https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/67367 for some references and further information about GCM.  I recommend you always use 96-bit _sequential_ nonces with AES-GCM.