# What does counter mean in Counter (CTR) Mode? Is it the same as nonce?

Tags: ctr

As asked above, what does "counter" mean exactly? Is it the same as nonce?

Also, the book Network Security Essentials (6ed.) from William Stallings states, "Typically the counter is initialized to some value and then incremented by 1 for each subsequent block (modulo $2^b$, where $b$ is the block size)". What does this statement mean exactly?

Answer (score 2):

> what does "counter" mean exactly?

Counter per Wikipedia definition;

> In digital logic and computing, a counter is a device that stores (and sometimes displays) the number of times a particular event or process has occurred

In CTR context; it is used to produce different inputs for the encryption, then the output is x-ored with the plaintext to produce a ciphertext. It is usually performed by incrementing, though one can use LFSR, too.

[image]

> Is it the same as nonce

No, it is not the same as the nonce ( number used once)

The CTR mode combines nonce and counter, as the input to the cipher. The input is combined from two parts;

- nonce part; typically generated randomly per encryption session or by use of [counter/LFSR](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/84380/18298).
- counter part; initially set zero, then incremented for every block encryption

With these we can have, randomized encryption and each block can produce a different output under the same key if we are using a PRP like AES ( PRF part is more complex and actually CTR is defined for PRFs since there is no need for the inverse)

> "Typically the counter is initialized to some value and then incremented by 1 for each subsequent block (modulo $2^b$, where $b$ is the block size)". What does this statement mean exactly?

Consider that we have 64-bit nonce and 64-bit counter;

```
 nonce              counter
9237AF71A232BC82E4 0000000000000000
```

First block uses  `9237AF71A232BC82E40000000000000000` as input, then the subsequent block uses as

```
 nonce              counter
9237AF71A232BC82E4 0000000000000001
9237AF71A232BC82E4 0000000000000002
9237AF71A232BC82E4 0000000000000003
9237AF71A232BC82E4 0000000000000004
 ...                   ...
9237AF71A232BC82E4 EFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
9237AF71A232BC82E4 FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
 ...                   ...
9237AF71A232BC82E5 0000000000000000 ???
```

If you can encrypt $2^{64}$ blocks you will reach the end of the counter, depending on the case this can be dangerous.

- If you continue from  0 counter `9237AF71A232BC82E40000000000000000` then you will have a nonce-reuse (two-time pad) issue in the CTR mode; confidentiality is lost. An observer can execute a manual crib-dragging even an automized one

  - [A natural language approach to automated cryptanalysis of two-time pads](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/%7Ejason/papers/mason+al.ccs06.pdf)
- If you continue increment than `9237AF71A232BC82E50000000000000000` you may hit another input that can turn into the two-time pad, too.

Stop there; actually, stop way before there [if you use PRP instead of PRF](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/85572/18298).

---

**Notes on different usages of the nonce IV term**;

- [NIST definition uses counter as the whole input](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-38a.pdf) for the encryption.
- Wikipedia makes a distinction. I've preferred Wikipedia's definition, In the GCM case, [NIST uses IV and counter separately.](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-38d.pdf)
- Lindell&Katz, on their book, uses IV as the $3n/4$ part of the block size and $1/4$ as for the counter. The encryption is defined as $y_i := F_k (IV || \langle i \rangle)$ They show that if the IV is uniformly selected then the IV reuse is a negligible event. Therefore CTR mode is CPA secure.

Comment: I know that CTR is CPA-secure without IV-reuse. Is it still CPA-secure, if one considers IV-reuse? I would say no, but I'm not 100\% sure.

Comment: @Titanlord It still has under some assumptions. Lindell and Katz deal with this in their book by assuming that the IV is chosen uniformly randomly, then the event is negligible if the IV size is $3n/4$.

Comment: The "IV" is not defined for CTR mode as far as I know. If it is there then implementations usually mean the starting value for the nonce & counter, i.e. the fully block used as initial input to the block cipher. In that case it is *not* equivalent to the nonce.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Lindell&Katz call it IV as $3n/4$ size of the block size $n$ with  $y_i := F_k (IV || <i>)$. Yes, I'm well aware that the original NIST doesn't call it IV, just call the whole input as a counter. I'm ready to be more consistent. Let me try. I guess they do this to show that the IV collision is negligible by selecting uniform random.

Comment: The book of Lindell & Katz is, in my opinion, not an authoritative reference for terms & definitions. The book also confuses secret and private keys after all; *you cannot share a private <anything>*. Of course you can define an "IV" 3n/4 the size of the block size, however *that's not how anybody else uses the term* - to my knowledge anyway.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Paar uses the same way, too. Amussen in Serious Cryptography, Bruce et, al in Cryptography engineering same as Wikipedia. Some other uses same as [original paper of Diffie-Hellman](https://ee.stanford.edu/~hellman/publications/32.pdf) everything is counter as NIST did.

Comment: Well, I cannot argue against that. Just note that most Crypto API's use IV as full input to the API. And since they generally use big endian modulo $2^n$ for the counter, the IV is exactly one block-size $n$; it's not separate from the counter or nonce. That way they are compatible with most definitions of counter mode (except WinZip, as mentioned in my answer, as it uses little endian).

Comment: Well, I see that it is not an agreement at all. I know you know much better than me about the API's. The APIs almost follow the original paper and NIST ( counter turns to IV), it is not that strange at all. Indeed we always say the IV reuse, in this case saying IV part instead of nonce still makes much sense ( I'll make clear that later). I was actually considering deleting this, however, when you noted it, I've looked at the source, again. There It stayed.

Answer (score 1):

No, the nonce and the counter are certainly distinct terms.

- The nonce is a unique value per message.
- The counter is a unique and sequential value for multiple blocks of the same message.

The nonce can be calculated in any way as long as it is unique. Usually it is either fully randomized, or it is sequential, starting at zero or one.

---

Although the counter is often *specified as separate from the nonce* in protocols, implementations usually have a counter that is the same size as the block size. In that case the nonce is part of the most significant bits of the starting counter.

This is reflected by the part of the book that you quote:

> Also, the book Network Security Essentials (6ed.) from William Stallings states:
>
> > "Typically the counter is initialized to some value and then incremented by 1 for each subsequent block (modulo $2^b$, where $b$ is the block size)".
>
> What does this statement mean exactly?

Let's assume a 128 bit block cipher such as AES. Then let's say that each byte is displayed by a letter, then you have:

```
 CCCCCCCC_CCCCCCCC = NNNNNNNN_00000000
```

where each C is a byte in the starting counter and N is a byte within the nonce. The starting counter is often treated as "IV". Now implementations will increase this initial value modulus $2^{128}$: i.e. when it hits $2^{128} - 1$ the next value will be all-zero.

However, that means that after $2^{64}$ increments your counter will increase the rightmost nonce byte, possibly leading to a duplicate counter value. **This means that the application itself needs to keep count how many blocks have been encrypted.** The reason for this is that the nonce can consist of *any amount of bytes*, so it doesn't know when the nonce is affected. In other words, the implementations don't know when an overflow into the nonce occurs or when counters collide.

---

Notes:

- In principle any scheme is valid for CTR as long as the counter does not repeat for the same key. Deriving a new key for each message gives you an almost infinite amount of blocks ($2^{128}$ 16 byte blocks for AES).
- Although the counter is not defined to be either big or little endian, big endian counters seem to prevail. I've come across one protocol that used a little endian counter though - WinZip if memory serves me right.
- The nonce may not be the only element that makes the (initial) counter unique, other data elements may be included in the (initial) counter value. Sometimes an identifier for domain separation is included such as an identifier for the receiver.
- NIST goes into detail about how to construct cipher blocks in NIST SP 800-38a, appendix B, noting at the end that counters are basically protocol specific, and that the uniqueness requirement must be tested separately.

Answer (score 0):

A nonce is a (random/pseudorandom) number used only once. And that is the only limitation to which it is subject. Thus nonce is merely a generic term.

In CTR Mode every value is different to each other and (in general) only used once. Therefore the initialization vector and resulting numbers can be viewed as nonces.

(Note: In some cases authors may explicitly make a distinction between CTR-values and nonces. If that's the case, they may have a different definition or more restrictions to consider)

Comment: Nonces don't need to be "random/pseudorandom," just unique (within the scope of a single key). In fact it's common to use a message counter (≠ block counter) as a nonce.