# Calculating maximum plaintexts without birthday collisions given a probability, when the encryption scheme has multiple parts?

Tags: collision-resistance

I'm sorry if the answer to this is actually simpler than it seems to me.

I'm running AES-GCM to encrypt some data keys, but I don't actually know how to go about calculating the probability of collisions for my setup, or how to derive the maximum number of plaintexts I can encrypt without violating NIST standards on key/IV reuse. I understand the math behind the birthday problem specifically (at least, the bit where each successive student has an (n-1)/365 chance of a matching birthday), but I don't know how I can apply it practically to the case below:

How would I find out the maximum number of plaintexts I can encrypt while remaining below a given collision probability for a scheme such as the following?

- For each plaintext, generate a 16-byte random value, a 32-byte random salt, and a 12-byte random IV.
- Hash the 16-byte random value with the 32-byte salt with something like HKDF (SHA-256).
- Encrypt a plaintext with the hash as a key and the 12-byte IV via AES-GCM.

*(For clarification, I'm hoping to learn a general method I can apply to figure out the answer to any similar/modified scheme)*

---

I know there are several methods (and even online calculators) for something like "approximate maximum keys given a 12-byte IV and maximum collision probability of 2<sup>-32</sup>" (it's 2<sup>32</sup>) and similarly for a 32-byte value (it's about 2<sup>112</sup>). But I get the feeling that even though both the hash and IV need to match to be a collision, simply multiplying numbers won't get the right number. My gut instinct says to multiply 2<sup>256</sup> and 2<sup>96</sup> to get 2<sup>352</sup> (because you need both the IV and hash output to be the same as another set of IV+hash to get a collision) and then approximate the chance of a collision using Stirling or Taylor with 2<sup>352</sup> as the "number of days in a year" space, but that can't be right...right?

<sub>Side note: I mention the hashing/salting process as well because I feel like hashing might increase the chance of collisions due to the Pigeonhole Principle-- I'm feeding in 16 + 32 bytes of input and getting 32 bytes as output, could this possibly affect the end result?</sub>

Comment: I think this extensive answer covers your needs and the bound for GCM is really complex issue. [Does GCM (or GHASH) only provide 64-bit security against forgeries?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/67261/18298)